# Custom query, checking values of multiple meta keys

Tags: php, wp-query, meta-query

I am using two plugins, and I have some issues combining them. One is an event calendar, which add new meta keys to posts, the other is a show-posts-as-grid plugin, that fetches the event posts from the calendar plugin using a custom query.

I need to have a custom query that only fetches event posts that have end-time before current time.

My issue is that the meta keys for the event's end time is not stored as a full timestamp, but split into 3 keys (see below).

```
pec_end_time_hh = '19'
pec_end_time_mm = '00'
pec_end_date = '2016-06-10'
```

If the end time was stored all in one meta key, I could do:

```
$query['meta_query'] = array(
  array(
    'key' => 'pec_end_datetime',
    'compare' => '<=',
    'value' => current_time('mysql')
  )
);
```

But since the end time is split in multiple keys, I am stuck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How did you go with this, zplirf?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `meta_query` to combine multiple queries using either AND or OR relation. Granted, it does get a bit complex in this case, but because you can nest multiple queries, you can still achieve it.

This is covered in the [WP_Meta_Query documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query#Initializing_WP_Meta_Query) and also to an extent in the [WP_Query docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).

Here's what I think should work. I haven't tested this, but it should do what you want: compare these three fields to make sure the event is in the past.

Scroll below the code for an explanation of what it's doing.

```
$query['meta_query'] = array(
  'relation' => 'OR',
  array(
    'key' => 'pec_end_datetime',
    'compare' => '<',
    'value' => current_time('Y-m-d'),
    'type' => 'DATE',
  ),
  array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
      'key' => 'pec_end_datetime',
      'compare' => '=',
      'value' => current_time('Y-m-d'),
      'type' => 'DATE',
    ),
    array(
      'key' => 'pec_end_time_hh',
      'compare' => '<',
      'value' => current_time('G'),
      'type' => 'NUMERIC',
    ),
  ),
  array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
      'key' => 'pec_end_datetime',
      'compare' => '=',
      'value' => current_time('Y-m-d'),
      'type' => 'DATE',
    ),
    array(
      'key' => 'pec_end_time_hh',
      'compare' => '=',
      'value' => current_time('G'),
      'type' => 'NUMERIC',
    ),
    array(
      'key' => 'pec_end_time_mm',
      'compare' => '<',
      'value' => current_time('i'),
      'type' => 'NUMERIC',
    ),
  ),
);
```

What we're doing is providing three different meta_queries with an OR relation. If any of them are true, the event is in the past:

- if the date is less than today's date, OR
- if the date is today AND the hour is less than the current hour, OR
- if the date is today, AND the hour is the current hour, AND the minute is less than the current minute

Unfortunately we can't combine all of these into one simple query, because we obviously don't want an event three hours in the future, at half past the hour, to come up as a past event when it's 45 minutes into the current hour!

The strings sent to `current_time()` all match the [PHP date formats](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).